# unexpected results of division and Modulus in c++

Tags: c++, operators

why 990099009900 / 10 equals to -203843547 in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long int n = 990099009900;
    cout << n / 10;
}
```

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xWeVVR5hSY9I93Ms)

Comment: Me neither. Is this really the code you tested?

Comment: On Windows, `long` has always 32 bit. Use `long long` or `int64_t`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 WandBox uses g++, where `long` on x64 has 64bit.

Comment: @rafix07 sometimes my fingers are faster than my brain :P. @OP try `cout << sizeof(long int);` to see what a `long int` can hold on your system. Also try `cout << n;`, when the end result is wrong it always helps to look at the intermidate steps

Comment: `long int` is defined to have **at least** 32bit and as of that only a guaranteed rang of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (it might have more, but only that range is guaranteed).  `990099009900` is out of that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this here:

```
std::cout << "limit " << std::numeric_limits<long int>::max();
```

You probably get `2147483647`, like how it happens on Visual Studio. Try `long long` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long n = 990099009900;
    std::cout << n / 10;
}
```

This is [guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) to be at least 64 bit, while `long int` isn't (that's at least 32 bit). 32 bits aren't enough to hold `990099009900`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `long long` for a number of that size in order for your code to be portable.

You are using a system where your `LONG_MAX` (i.e. `std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`) is smaller than 990099009900.

This flexibility has its drawbacks which is one reason why the fixed width types like `std::int64_t` were introduced.

Another approach is to use

```
auto n = 990099009900;
```

and let the compiler figure it out, although that can cause problems if you're close to the limit of the type, and you increase `n`.